# Str_replace is not working

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a PHP snippet in DB that I fetch through query,After that I apply str_replace on it to replace a particular Area.

```
str_replace("****",$res->id,$my_file);
```

But it is not changing the string.
I dont know how to debug the scenrio

Comment: How are you using it? Like `str_replace(...,...,...);` or `$myVar = str_replace(...,...,...);`

Comment: It ***returns*** replaced string.

Comment: @Zaffy it does't works still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the returned string to your variable. None of PHP's `*_replace` functions modify the original string in-place.

```
$my_file = str_replace("****", $res->id, $my_file);
```